# associated-domains has a conflict with com.apple.developer.web-browser setting

Tags: ios-universal-links, default-browser, associated-domains

I created an application with the com.apple.developer.web-browser (set default browser) function, but when I want to add the Universal link function to this application, I found that the Universal link function is invalid. I searched for this problem for a long time, until finally I found that it has something to do with com.apple.developer.web-browser settings, when I turn off com.apple.developer.web-browser, Universal link works again. But my app needs to have both, has anyone encountered such a problem? Can you provide some solutions?Thanks anyway.

I try to add WKAppBoundDomains in my Info.plist,but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.